# How does Ubuntu One perform when renaming folders?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have a (somewhat) large collection of media files on Ubuntu One which I need to reorganise (locally) by changing folder names, etc.

In this situation (say a folder "photos A B" renamed to "photos_a_b"), how does Ubuntu One behave?

Does it re-upload all the files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renaming just renames the folder. No re-upload. Otherwise, it'd be really crappy and it isn't. :)

Answer (score -3):

It is not possible to rename folders on the Ubuntu One site. I have just tried it. So, my answer is that Ubuntu One will see the renamed folders as new folders and upload the folder and its contents on to the Ubuntu One server.

Regards.

Comment: that was just a wild guess and it was wrong. please don't do that.

Comment: True, it is not possible to rename folders on the website. However renaming a folder on your computer does not result in the contents of that directory being uploaded again.